# How can I keep track of twitter usernames in Address Book?

Tags: contacts, twitter

I want to add twitter names to my contacts in Address Book. But I cannot find an obvious place to do so.

The best fit would be as instant messaging username, but twitter is not listed among the services. I there a way to add a service here? Does anyone know where they are stored?

I could add a new "twitter" label, but I can't stand the "AIM" or "Yahoo" behind it.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Clearly, the best solution would be Apple pimping the Address Book. They should allow adding/deleting of Social Networks. Each social network could have an associated URL scheme that is derived from the user ID. All other solutions are somewhat crappy. Dreaming…

Comment: highly disagree with @ortwin given the answers below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iOS 5.0 and Mac OS X Lion have native support for Twitter integrated into the Address Book app. On OS X, to add a Twitter field to a contact, select the contact and choose the `Card > Add Field > Twitter` menu item.

Comment: I think radven above got it right for Lion and iOS 5.![screen shot of address book template editor](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F4vDR.png)

Comment: This is the best solution right now. Accepted.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to the comments on Ipacheco's answer, I ended using a new url labeled "twitter" with a format of "tweetie:@someone" instead of the http:// link to the twitter homepage. This opens up tweetie for Mac and iPhone (now named twitter) whenever you click the link.

Comment: that's a nice trick!

Answer (score 6):

You could add an URL to the Twitter home of your contact and label it Twitter.

Comment: Yeah, this is also what happens, it seems, if in iPhone's Twitter app you view a person's profile and then choose "Create New Contact" or "Add to Existing Contact". (Except instead of a normal http url, it now sets the value to "twitter:@username".)

Comment: If there was a (simple) way to register the twitter URI on the Mac OS X, I would prefer using "twitter:@username". As it is, using the "http", it works on both Mac an iPhone, but in the iPhone it will open Safari instead of the Twitter application. Using "twitter", the URL won't open on the Mac.

Comment: Can't find it right now but there are apps for OS X that let you assign new apps to new URIs.

Comment: Since I am using tweetie on the mac and the phone tweetie:@someone workes well for me. +1 to Jonik

Answer (score 0):

modify your adressbook template as per this post:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/vanderwal/3629218638/

then add a little prefpane called MoreInternet as per this post:
http://www.macwrite.com/critical-mass/protocol-helpers-and-mac-os-x

use e.g. twitter: as "protocol" ... so for me you'd add twitter:@trox in a twitter URL field
configure the prefpane to recognize twitter as a protocol and tell it which app to use (your preferred twitter client -- works only if it has a "creator code", so I wasn't able to use TweetDeck :-o)

you're all set

Comment: You don't need to modify the template or add the prefpane to take advantage of url like twitter:@trox - just add it in as a web page and you are golden.